# How to center my page content when browser window is in full screen, and extend my footer across the entire page?

Tags: php, css, footer, transition, shift

Please take a look at [this site](http://croganm.net76.net)

Mess around with the browser window size for a little bit (I'm on Chrome and have not tried it with other browsers) and you will notice that my website takes up the entire page when the browser window is taking up only half of the monitor, but when the browser is in full screen mode, the content of the website stays to the left side of the webpage and the white margins get bigger. Also, my footer doesn't take up the entire page.

I don't want the site design to change, I just want all my site content to be shifted to the middle of the page when in full screen mode. I also want my footer rather then to be just sitting at the bottom of page only taking up part of it, extending across the entire page

HTML Code

```
<html !DOCTYPE>
<head>
  <title>Mathew Crogan's Website</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <form action="form.php" method="POST" id="form">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>Name:
        <br>
        <input name="contact_name" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>Email address:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="contact_email">
        <br>
        <br>Message:
        <br>
        <textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <div style="height:60px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF; position:absolute; margin-left:0px; margin-top:200px;width:275px; text-align:center;">
        <h3>Contact Me!</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
         <h1>Welcome To My Website!</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="firstlink"> <a id="firstlink" href="form.php">Main</a>

    </div>
    <div id="secondlink"> <a id="secondlink" href="me.php">Who I Am</a>

    </div>
    <div id="rollover"> <a id="rollover" href="project.php">Projects</a>
 <a id="rollover" href="code.php">Code Used For These Pages</a>

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="condiv">
        <p id="content">This is a website where I, Mathew Crogan, test out <i>HTML</i> or <i>PHP</i> or <i>CSS</i> Coding</p>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        <img id="me" src="img/1235154_462876267144148_1500701414_n.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Web Designer: Mathew Crogan
        <br>You are allowed to use this code. You can copy it from the "Code Used From These Pages" section. In order to use this code however, you must <b>GIVE CREDIT TO MATHEW CROGAN AND ASK FOR HIS PERMISSION USING THE "Contact Me" SECTION OF HIS MAIN PAGE</b>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css:

```
html {
    height:500px;
    width:1000px;
    ;
}
#header {
    height: 75px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left:25px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    float:left;
}
#form {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
#content {
    color:red;
}
#condiv {
    height:320px;
    width:420px;
    margin-left:315px;
    margin-top:160px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius:25px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#image {
    height:350px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    left:800px;
    bottom:380px;
}
#me {
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-radius:25px;
}
#secondlink {
    margin-left:190px;
}
a#rollover:link, a#rollover:visited {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#B5B5B5;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:8px;
}
a#rollover:hover, a#rollover:active {
    background-color:#A7A7A7;
}
a#firstlink:link, a#firstlink:visited {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#B5B5B5;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    height:44px;
    padding-top:8px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:105px;
    margin-left:343px;
}
a#firstlink:hover, a#firstlink:active {
    background-color:#A7A7A7;
}
a#secondlink:link, a#secondlink:visited {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#B5B5B5;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:8px;
}
a#secondlink:hover, a#secondlink:active {
    background-color:#A7A7A7;
}
#footer {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#B5B5B5;
    width:1000px;
    position:absolute height:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

Comment: You can always draw a picture, of what you would want your site to look like because what you have told us is quite blurry.

Comment: I know, I kind of tried to explain it better but it didn't come out right. I don't want the site design to change, I just want all my site content to be shifted to the middle of the page when in full screen mode. I also want my footer rather then to be just sitting at the bottom of page only taking up part of it, extending across the entire page

Comment: I would like to answer, but it'll cover too much, because you don't fully understand how `box` works, but I'll try.

Comment: Have you tried putting the entire contents of your body into one div and then setting that div's margin to '0 auto'?

Comment: Mathew, I think you should search the web for "flexible layout", "elastic layout" and "responsive design". Reading tutorials about these topics will teach you more about how to do HTML layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can centre the whole body so you can have the space on both sides:

```
html {
  height:500px;
  width:1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

This is [the most common method](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml) to center `block` elements in css, as explained in the link. However, I'd change it to something even more common:

```
html {
  width: 100%:
  }
body {
  height:500px;
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

In this way, you can be assured that the html is the "base" for your meassures, and it's the full width of the page. Then you can work with the body. Also I set it a little smaller, to 960px, because one of the common resolutions is 1024px wide and with the scrollbars and other things it gets to just above that measure.

Lastly, the footer is a story apart that needs a huge article. And other people has already done it, it's called `sticky footer`, and google will provide enough information:

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/